# C assignment of int

Tags: c++, c, unix, gcc, variable-assignment

When you see code like this in C, what's the order of assignment?

```
int i = 0, var1, var2;
```

I don't understand the syntax...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only `i` is assigned the value zero.

`var1` and `var2` are uninitialized.

Comment: Uninitialized might be better. We know what you mean, but "uninitialized" is not only far more common (a buzz word), but carries the weight it should have: reading them leads to undefined behavior. Technically, `i` is unassigned too, because it's never been assigned (with strict adherence to the language definition of "assignment") a value.

Comment: var1 and var2 are uninitialized may not be correct unless we know the overall context of this declaration. These could be initialized to 0 if the declaration is in namespace scope.

Comment: @Chubsdad: I'm referring to that single declaration line.

Answer (score 7):

There's no "assignment" in your code whatsoever. It is a declaration of three variables of type `int`, of which one is *initialized* with zero. The `=` symbol is an integral part of initialization syntax, it has nothing to do with any "assignment". And since there's only *one* initialization there, there's really no question about any "order".

If that doesn't answer your question, clarify it.

Answer (score 4):

There is only one assignment (i=0), the rest are definitions.

Comment: That's initialization, not assignment.

Comment: @GMan you are correct. I am leaving it as it is though, for the record.

Answer (score 4):

`i` is initialized to `0` whereas variables `var1` and `var2` are uninitialized and thus have unspecified values(if they are defined in a local scope).

Comment: 'i' is assigned the value 0 is also not correct. 'i' is initialized with 0

Comment: @Chubsdad: Yes I should have corrected that after reading AndreyT's answer.

Answer (score 0):

All of them are local variables , the only difference is i has been assigned a value zero whereas the values of var1 and var2 are unpredictable, they will have garbage values.